# protobuf-net.grpc Client Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, protobuf-net

I was previously using `Grpc.AspNetCore` but am trying to migrate to `protobuf-net.grpc` because I much prefer the code-first approach given that it's more idiomatically dotnet and the whole solution is built on dotnet, so having `.proto` files and code-gens just causes a bit of a mess.

So I've created my service as per [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/code-first?view=aspnetcore-6.0):

```cs
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAdService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<HorseSaleAdReply> GetHorseSaleAds(AdRequest adRequest, CallContext context = default);
}
```

As far as I can tell, this works nicely.

However, I now want to create a client for this service and have it injected. The docs suggest this approach:

```cs
using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:7184");
        var client = channel.CreateGrpcService<IGreeterService>();

        var reply = await client.SayHelloAsync(
            new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient" });
```

However, when I try and wrap that in a singleton:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton(_ => {
using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:7184");
        return channel.CreateGrpcService<IAdService>();
})
```

And inject it into one of my classes, I get an error about the channel having already been disposed.

Would you be able to advise on how I can correctly inject these clients?

My only other idea would be to create a client class that implements `IDisposable`, stores a reference to that channel and does it that way. However, this seems like it really ought to be unnecessary.

Comment: You've answered your own question in the last paragraph. The singleton instance creation function runs and then leaves scope, so the channel is disposed immediately. Creating a custom IDisposable implementation for this is a quite natural thing to do IMHO.

Comment: +1 to what Ray said. I would probably build a manager class that holds the channel and clients, and inject that as a singleton. Seems very counter-intuitive to immediately create the gRPC channel with a connection address and clients and inject them as a singleton, instead of having the option to create (and then dispose) them when they are actually used...